# How do I reliably get the correct timestamp for 0001-01-01 from Hive 3 and Spark 3?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, timestamp, timezone

I have a very basic csv of new year dates all the way from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 to 0000-01-01 00:00:00, which I've made available to Hive as external table `test.ny(dt string)`. The time zone on all machines is Europe/Moscow

When I create a parquet table in Hive 2:

```
create table test.ny2 stored as parquet
as
select 
dt, 
unix_timestamp(dt||' 00:00:00') dt2,
cast(dt as timestamp) dt3
from test.ny --this is my csv
```

I am able to access it via spark-sql if I `set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead=LEGACY`. All dt3 values are read correctly as `YYYY-01-01 00:00:00`

However, when I access the same table via Hive 3, I get a discrepancy at

```
dt                  dt2         dt3
1901-01-01 00:00:00 -2177461817 1901-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 00:00:00 -2208999600 1899-12-31 23:30:17.000
```

which can be explained by the tzdb being applied incorrectly in Hive 2, and another one at the very end:

```
dt                  dt2             dt3
0003-01-01 00:00:00 -62072708400    0002-12-29 23:30:17.000
0002-01-01 00:00:00 -62104244400    0001-12-29 23:30:17.000
0001-01-01 00:00:00 -62135780400    0001-12-29 23:30:17.000
0000-01-01 00:00:00 -62167402800    0002-12-29 23:30:17.000
```

That's not all. When I recreate the same table in Hive 3.1.3 from scratch:

```
create table test.ny3 stored as parquet
as
select 
dt, 
unix_timestamp(dt||' 00:00:00') dt2,
cast(dt as timestamp) dt3
from test.ny --this is my csv
```

I get the second error when I select it in Hive!

```
dt                  dt2             dt3
0003-01-01 00:00:00 -62072697600    0003-01-01 00:00:00.000
0002-01-01 00:00:00 -62104233600    0002-01-01 00:00:00.000
0001-01-01 00:00:00 -62135769600    0002-01-01 00:00:00.000
0000-01-01 00:00:00 -62167392000    0002-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I also cannot select the data I want via spark-sql, no matter what mode I use, LEGACY (which is understandable):

```
dt                       dt2             dt3
0003-01-01 00:00:00      -62072697600    0003-01-03 00:29:43
0002-01-01 00:00:00      -62104233600    0002-01-03 00:29:43
0001-01-01 00:00:00      -62135769600    0001-01-03 00:29:43
0000-01-01 00:00:00      -62167392000    0001-01-03 00:29:43
```

or CORRECTED (which it gets almost right):

```
dt                       dt2             dt3
0003-01-01 00:00:00      -62072697600    0003-01-01 00:00:00
0002-01-01 00:00:00      -62104233600    0002-01-01 00:00:00
0001-01-01 00:00:00      -62135769600    0001-01-01 00:00:00
0000-01-01 00:00:00      -62167392000    0001-01-01 00:00:00 --notice the year!
```

Question 1: what's with Hive 3 failing to correctly process existing timestamps around years 0000 and 0001?

Question 2: how can I read both old (written by Hive 2) and new (written by Hive 3) tables in the same Spark session?

- how do I get Hive 3 to use the old calendar and tzdb logic, so I can read all tables in LEGACY mode, or
- how do I correct Hive 2 tables in Hive 3 to use the new calendar and tzdb logic, so I can read all tables in Spark in CORRECTED mode?

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't quite make sense.  The TZDB has no information for `Europe/Moscow` [before 1880](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2022g/europe#L2552).  Your data is off due to LMT offset used for dates before then.  It's also hard to know what you mean by "old calendar" and "new calendar" here.  If you're dealing with true Gregorian or Julian calendars, you can't go back that far because they didn't exist then.  However, you can certainly use the ISO8601 calendar (which has a year 0) - but then all values should be UTC, not Moscow Time.

Comment: The "old calendar" is the Gregorian + proleptic Julian calendar Spark 2 and Hive 2 use. The "new calendar" is the proleptic Georgian calendar Spark 3 and Hive 3 use.

Comment: Also, Hive 2 and Spark 2 use, as far as I understand, the value for the current date from the tzdb for dates earlier than 1900, and Hive 3 and Spark 3 use the real offset from the TZDB or the oldest offset they can find.

Answer (score 0):

Hive3 doesnt support legacy timestamps, it was introduced at some way in 4.* versions only

Comment: This answers the question I came with, except I wish there was some evidence or context to confirm this relates to the legacy dates mentioned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31404. Do you have a link for this Hive release issue or a definition of "legacy" in your comment? Closest I found was: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22241 which is supported in Hive 3.1.3, but not sure it's quite the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp doesn't appear to be the right datatype for this task.

In the examples you provide, the time resolution within a day doesn't seem to change, as such it's better to use the `to_date` and operate on the daily frequency. If the sub-day frequency matters for downstream operations, it should be feasible to just append '00:00:00' where appropriate.

Comment: It's not the right datatype, but that's what I am stuck with, as downstream marts are not ready for a schema change.

Comment: Would it work to add the hour-minute-second component at the very end of the pipeline (before passing downstream)?